# How to access variable in prototype

Tags: javascript, d3.js, closures

How can i pass the context of

```
   Test = function(){
    this.x = //(1) How to access this in the return ?

    this.line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function (d) {
            return this.x(d.x);
        })

 }
```

this.x in the return will give context not as in (1)
How can i access 1 in the return ?

Comment: *this* isn't "context", it's a parameter that is set by how a function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to bind the function with the current object, with [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), like this

```
this.line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function (d) {
        return this.x(d.x);
    }.bind(this))
```

Since the anonymous function is bound to the current object `this`, inside the function, `this` refer to the actual `this` bound.

The other common way is to retain the `this` object, like this

```
Test = function() {
    var that = this;               // Retain the value of `this`
    this.x = 1;

    this.line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("linear")
        .x(function(d) {
            return that.x(d.x);    // Use `that`, instead of `this`
        })
}
```

Comment: Can I change the this context to something else<pre> <code>
this.line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function (d) {
        return this.x(d.x);
    }.bind(this))</pre></code>
Such that I can call 
this.line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function (d) {
        return that.x(d.x);
    }.bind(this))

Comment: @Ecko123 Context can be any valid object.